# how can i apply if loop in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have two date fields, if a user selects only one date then function A should get executed, else if both date are selected then function A and B should get executed. I am using jquery datepicker 
These are my two onselect functions:

```
$(function () {
    $("#SelectA").datepicker({
        onSelect: function (date) {
            A = $('#SelectA').val();
            Method(A, "", "");
        }
    });
});

$(function () {
    $("#SelectB").datepicker({
        onSelect: function (date) {
            A = $('#SelectA').val();
            B = $('#SelectB').val();
            Method(A, B, "");
        }
    });
});
```

The question is that how do i implement IF loop in here? And do i need to terminate functionA and re-invoke it when function B is selected?

```
        function Method(A,B,C) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Services/MethodName.asmx/Method",
            data: JSON.stringify({ A: A, B: B, C: C }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                place the data into a table
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my datepicker:

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
    var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

    var checkin = $('#dpd1').datepicker({
        onRender: function (date) {
            return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
            var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
            checkout.setValue(newDate);
        }
        checkin.hide();
        $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
    }).data('datepicker');
    var checkout = $('#dpd2').datepicker({
        onRender: function (date) {
            return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        checkout.hide();
    }).data('datepicker');
```

Comment: You'll have to show us `Method()`, the only way we can write something that will let you terminate the function, is if we can see what the function does.

Comment: method gets some data from the database and populated into some table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on what you're asking, but I think this might solve your problem (assuming the server knows how to handle blank values):

```
$(function () {
    $("#SelectA").datepicker({
        onSelect: handleSelectedDates
    });
    $("#SelectB").datepicker({
        onSelect: handleSelectedDates
    });

    function handleSelectedDates(date) {
        var A = $('#SelectA').val();
        var B = $('#SelectB').val();

        Method(A, B, "");                
    }

    var ajaxReq;
    function Method(A,B,C) {
        if (ajaxReq)
            ajaxReq.abort();
        ajaxReq = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Services/MethodName.asmx/Method",
            data: JSON.stringify({ A: A, B: B, C: "" }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                place the data into a table
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the jQuery datepicker (which this question has not yet been tagged), then you can simply use the `onSelect` method which will return the dates, which you can then check against and `if` statement and run your custom code.

Here is a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/xu8zZ/

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
         console.log(dateText);
            console.log(inst);
        }
    });
  });
```

Just look at your console when you select a date and you will see how it returns the date; at which time, you can write your condition.

Ref. http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

Answer (score 0):

You can use one function to handle both events:

```
$(function () {
  $("#SelectA,#SelectB").datepicker({
    onSelect: function (date) {
      var A = $('#SelectA').val();

      if ($(this).attr("id") == "SelectB")
      {
        var B = $('#SelectB').val();
      }
      else
      {
        var B = "";
      }
      var C = "";
      Method(A, B, C);
    }
  });
});
```